# Fixning chromatic aberration lens error in software

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I am looking for a method to correct chromatic aberration in c#. I am using aforge and like to use this library to do this, but if it is not possible, I will use other tools.

Where can I find the algorithm to do this?

Can I do it using aforge?

Is there any library/sample code that I can use to do this?

Comment: Hi - any news? did you find a solution? THX

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article by Farid et alia](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/farid/downloads/publications/acm06c.pdf).

You may also find useful [Farid's notes on Digital Image Forensics](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/farid/downloads/tutorials/digitalimageforensics.pdf),
this document contains matlab code for chromatic aberration estimation and correction.